# how to work with std::thread on freeRTOS?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stm32, freertos, keil

I'm using freeRTOS on an stm32f407 with keil ide and arm compiler version 6 and g++17 and I don't like to work with freeRTOS threading APIs. instead, I want to work with std::thread c++ native library. but when I include `#include <thread>`, keil throws this error: `error: <thread> is not supported on this single threaded system`.

what is the problem?

when I have freeRTOS it means my platform is not single-threaded, so why keil throws this error?

Comment: Does the C++ standard library work _at all_ on an RTOS? It's hardly "native". You're working close to the metal: use the tools the OS gives you.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I have 3 threads running simultaneously right now! (I've created them with freeRTOS API). so, it means it is capable for multi-threading. right?

Comment: Not in the sense that a typical C++ implementation would understand, though. It's probably looking for `pthreads` or somesuch thing. C++17 is really a very peculiar choice for a FreeRTOS installation. Usually you'd be in C and use the FreeRTOS features.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings so you mean there is no way to use c++ thread library on freeRTOS? I really need to use c++ `std::threads`.

Comment: @MahyarShokraeian You'll need to implement all the OS bindings that `std::thread` needs, i.e. the POSIX pthread functions. I remember we've once done that, but it's not an easy task, and we decided to write our own threading abstraction classes with mostly the same semantics. This abstraction we could at least keep most of the code portable for the other µLinux based systems we developped. Same for the mutexes, semaphores and other related stuff.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks for helping! but, is there any open-source implementation of the bindings available on internet?

Comment: @MahyarShokraeian Nope, at least there weren't at that time (5-8 years ago). We would have used such of course, if it existed.

Comment: _"I really need to use c++ std::threads"_ Why's that? It's a very strange requirement on an embedded platform. How did you come to this conclusion during your architecture design research?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings because I've developed my software on a linux board with c++ and now I'm moving from linux to bare-metal. and my software is so complicated and I've used hundreds of multi-threaded libraries. It takes months for me to change all of them to use freeRTOS API. so this is the reason that I need a wrapper between RTOS and C++ native thread library!

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings also I found some FreeRTOS C++ wrappers but they haven't implemented `std::thread`. they've only implemented `std::mutex` and some other basic features. but I need `std::thread` wrapper the most!

Comment: Sounds like your code is missing a few abstractions!!!

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Take a look at [this freeRTOS C++](https://github.com/richard-damon/FreeRTOScpp) repo

Comment: @MahyarShokraeian What about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keil throws that error because you are linking your application against a library that does not support the  API.

There's a freeRTOS [POSIX threading wrapper](https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Plus/FreeRTOS_Plus_POSIX/index.html) you can possibly evaluate to use, or you could create another abstraction layer on top of CMSIS OS API.

There is also a C++ wrappers project, [freeRTOS-addons](https://github.com/michaelbecker/freertos-addons), that provides a convenient set of classes/APIs, but it has been inactive for years now.

Before going for a wrapper, one must evaluate why using an RTOS at all if its features of determinism and tasks priority mechanisms will not be used as equal priority tasks will share CPU time. Yet, of course, there are other benefits.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not really about C++17 itself, it’s all about the compiler/STL feature support for e.g. FreeRTOS platform. You know, someone has to implement the gory, low level details for a certain OS platform to provide a compliant  std::thread interface. The same applies to std::mutex and other related features which all require OS support. So you’d have to ask your (cross)compiler provider to build one with e.g. std::thread support for FreeRTOS.

Comment: thank you for your answer! but how can I ask my compiler to build std::thread support for FreeRTOS?

Comment: _@HS2_ _"So you’d have to ask your (cross)compiler provider to build one with e.g. std::thread support for FreeRTOS."_ Note, that most people simply use GCC to work with those ARM derivates.

Comment: I‘m also using GCC, the _bare metal_ binary distribution from ARM. _Bare metal_ means that there is no dedicated OS support built in. Hence we simply can’t use some C++17 features and have to use the native RTOS API. @Mahyar You could ask Keil for it but I doubt that there willing or able to do that. It’s hard work, costs a lot of money and they would have to do the same again for their RTX OS..

Answer (score 1):

Many of us just roll our own C++ wrappers for FreeRTOS APIs, or incorporated the FreeRTOS calls into classes where they're hidden from most of the application. You might want to have a look at this, which does mostly what you're looking for: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1278513/Cplusplus11-FreeRTOS-GCC